# Arduino with external Wi-Fi antenna?

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi, mkr1000

I need to create a project where I need to send data via Wi-Fi using an `Arduino`.

I need the `Arduino` to have a `U.FL connector` to place an external `Wi-Fi antenna` (I can't use the `MKR1000` with integrated `Wi-Fi` antenna because the `Arduino` will be placed inside a metal box).

Is there any solution-like `Arduino` for this without the need to use an external board like: `SparkFun WiFi Shield - ESP8266` ?

I could also use the `BeagleBoard Green Wireless` that contains this `U.FL connector` for an `Wi-Fi` antenna, but I wanted something smaller such as an `Arduino`.

PS: `Wi-Fi` is the only option.

Comment: some Wemos board clones have U.FL connector as alternative to on-board antenna https://robotdyn.com/wifi-d1-mini-esp8266-dev-board-usb-cp2104.html

Comment: It is commonly stated that many WIFI components have 50ohm impedance.  If true then swapping out internal and external antennas may be possible.  Even on boards which do not have an external antenna connector.  Notice that the SparkFun product you pointed to might be switchable to the external antenna by un-soldering, moving and re-soldering a jumper on the PCB (moving R10 to position R11 which is a do-not-place part).

Comment: I had "Grove UART Wifi" V1.0 with ceramic antenna in a metal box without external antenna. the AP was upstairs and the esp8266 worked without problems